# Container element not found in Blazor server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to embed an audio player using a javascript library called Wavesurfer.js in my Blazor component. I'm setting the IDs of the needed divs by generating GUIDs for them in the `razor.cs` page, then handing those values to the `.razor` component:

```
// WavePlayer.razor.cs
private Guid _mainDivGuid;
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        _interop = new WavesurferJsInterop(_js, DotNetObjectReference.Create<WavePlayer>(this));

        if (_interop != null)
        {
            await _interop.Create(_mainDivGuid, Options);
            //preload file if URL already supplied
            if (Url != null)
            {
                await Load(Url);
            }
        }
    }
}

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    _mainDivGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
}

// WavePlayer.razor
<div class="wavesurfer-ui-main" id="@_mainDivGuid"></div>
```

In the js interop it calls the actual wavesurfer.js where the `Create` method is invoked, and passes the GUID of the div where the player should get rendered.

When I run the component, I'm getting an error `Error: Container element not found` and I can confirm this in the js by adding a test for

```
if (!document.getElementById(mainDivGuid)) {
    console.log(mainDivGuid);
    console.log("No div element found for wavesurfer mainDivGuid"); // this gets logged
}
```

`mainDivGuid` is being created, it's the correct GUID, but by the time the `Create` method is invoked, the div apparently doesn't exist in the DOM.

Shouldn't using the `OnAfterRenderAsync` method ensure that the DOM is fully rendered before the `Create` gets called? I'm not sure how the wave player can be trying to fire its own events before the container exists!

Comment: Do you have both `_mainDivGuid` and `mainDivGuid`?

Comment: the private variable in the code behind is _mainDivGuid-- when it's passed into the interop it's renamed to mainDivGuid, but it's the same value

Comment: You can verify by viewing the rendered source that the `<div>` with that id value exists?

Comment: My team has also experienced this (the element we needed to interact on not yet being rendered in `OnAfterRender()`), but I cannot remember what the reason was. We put in a 100 ms delay before calling the interop function to get around it. Hopefully someone else has an appropriate answer as to why it happens and how best to handle it.

Comment: @Lex I can't verify the div exists since the app errors out-- I can verify in the js that the div does *not* exist when the js runs.

Comment: @AstridE. Interesting...I've had to do that to ensure the SyncFusion SfToast component has rendered because I was sometimes getting a null reference exception, but I figured that was just something specific to their implementation. Just out of curiosity, what render mode are you both using? I've switched to always using `Server` because `ServerPrerendered` was causing me some other grief.

Comment: Try initialising the field `private Guid _mainDivGuid =  Guid.NewGuid();` instead of doing that in the `OnInitialized` method.

Comment: @Lex We are using WebAssembly in our Blazor WASM application.

Comment: @Lex ServerPrerendered

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `ElementReference` when you work between JS and .NET code. Something like below:

```
// WavePlayer.razor

@inject IJSRuntime Js

<div class="wavesurfer-ui-main" ref="@_mainDiv"></div>

@code {
    public ElementReference _mainDiv;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await Js.InvokeVoidAsync("Create", _mainDiv);
        }
    }
}
```

In the JS your function argument will be the DOM object.

```
function Create(thisIsTheDomObjectHere) {
  thisIsTheDomObjectHere.innerHTML("Hi there");
}
```

See more here:

https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-javascript-from-dotnet/passing-html-element-references/

Comment: the wavesurfer js library expects a js selector rather than an element-- is there a way to get the selector from the `ElementReference`? Thanks

Comment: Sure. In my example above you can do something like `let selector = "#" + thisIsTheDomObjectHere.id;`

Comment: that doesn't seem to work, because when you view the actual element blazor never ties an `id` property to the created div. I think the `id` is internal to blazor, it's not an HTML property

Comment: Assign your own ‘id’ to it.

Comment: Right, but that defeats the purpose of using an ElementReference, as far as I can see. Docs say not to assign an ID but instead to use a ref, but once you have a ref you can't get the ID for the js interop'd library to handle if needed.

Comment: Consider it this way. For dotnet use the ElementReference. For JS use the id.